# Running Eureka Client with JDK 1.7

Tags: java, compiler-errors, microservices, netflix-eureka

I am getting following error when running a eureka client discovery sample code.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/netflix/servo/monitor/Monitors : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

I guess this is probably due to the fact that eureka is compiled with Java 8 (52).
But does it mean that we can not use it with JDK 1.7 ? My project is in JDK7 and is it possible to run eureka(1) with JDK 1.7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running the official sample application use the correct dependencies, servo-core latest dependencies are compiled with JDK8, Use an older version

```
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.netflix.servo</groupId>
           <artifactId>servo-core</artifactId>
           <version>0.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

README.md says:

> Building
>
> The build requires java8 because of some required libraries that are
>   java8 (servo), but the source and target compatibility are still set
>   to 1.7.

Reference:
https://github.com/Netflix/eureka

Comment: Then Why Am I getting that compatibility issue ?